# Incapaz de localizar JTA Transaction corrente

Tags: mvc, hibernate, spring, jsp, transações

O projeto está divido nos seguintes módulos:

- teste-persistence;
- teste-services;
- teste-web;

Utilizo o Glassfish 4 como servidor de aplicação e este possui um pool de conexão configurado para conexões com o banco de dados criado no MySQL.

> Classe de Serviço utilizada:

**UsuarioService**

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class UsuarioService implements IUsuarioService {

    private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;

    @Autowired
    public UsuarioService(UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO) {
        this.usuarioDAO = usuarioDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void salvar(Usuario pUsuario) {
        pUsuario.setStatus(Status.DISPONIVEL);
        this.usuarioDAO.salvar(pUsuario);
    }

    @Override
    public void atualizar(Usuario pUsuario) {
        this.usuarioDAO.atualizar(pUsuario);
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(Usuario pUsuario) {
        this.usuarioDAO.excluir(pUsuario);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public Usuario carregar(Integer pUsuario) {
        return this.usuarioDAO.carregar(pUsuario);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public Usuario carregarPorLogin(String pLogin) {
        return this.usuarioDAO.carregarPorLogin(pLogin);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public Usuario carregarPorRg(String pRg) {
        return this.usuarioDAO.carregarPorRg(pRg);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public List<Usuario> listar() {
        return this.usuarioDAO.listar();
    }
}
```

> Arquivos de configuração do Spring:

**spring-config-persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.teste.dao.impl" />
    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />

    <!-- Configuração do Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.teste.model" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    true
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">
                    true
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generator_mappings">
                    true
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
                </prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/TESTE_Pool" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
</beans
```

**spring-config-services.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <import resource="classpath*:/spring-config-persistence.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.teste.rn" />
</beans>
```

**spring-config-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...>

    <import resource="classpath*:/spring-config-services.xml" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.teste.web.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

> Arquivo de configuração web:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app ...>
    <display-name>teste-web</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config-web.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

> Página JSP utilizada:

**cadastro_usuario.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cadastro de Usuários</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form modelAttribute="usuario" action="executar_cadastro"
        method="POST">

        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <form:input path="nome" />

        <label for="login">Login:</label>
        <form:input path="login" />

        <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
        <form:input path="senha" />

        <label for="rg">RG:</label>
        <form:input path="rg" />

        <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
        <form:input path="cpf" />

        <label for="endereco.endereco">Endereço:</label>
        <form:input path="endereco.endereco" />

        <label for="endereco.numero">Número:</label>
        <form:input path="endereco.numero" />

        <label for="endereco.complemento">Complemento:</label>
        <form:input path="endereco.complemento" />

        <label for="endereco.cep">CEP:</label>
        <form:input path="endereco.cep" />

        <label for="endereco.bairro">Bairro:</label>
        <form:input path="endereco.bairro" />

        <label for="endereco.cidade">Cidade:</label>
        <form:input path="endereco.cidade" />

        <label for="endereco.estado">Estado:</label>
        <form:input path="endereco.estado" />

        <label for="contato.telefone">Número do Telefone:</label>
        <form:input path="contato.telefone" />

        <label for="contato.celular">Número do Celular:</label>
        <form:input path="contato.celular" />

        <label for="observacoes">Observações:</label>
        <form:input path="observacoes" />

        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar"></input>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

> Classe Controller utilizada:

**UsuarioController**

```
@Controller
public class UsuarioController {

    private IUsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Autowired
    public UsuarioController(IUsuarioService usuarioService) {
        this.usuarioService = usuarioService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cadastro_usuario")
    public String cadastro(Map<String, Object> model) {
        if (model.get("usuario") == null) {
            model.put("usuario", new Usuario());
        }

        return "cadastro_usuario";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/executar_cadastro", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String executarCadastro(Usuario usuario) {
        usuarioService.salvar(usuario);

        return "redirect:/cadastro_usuario"; 
    }
}
```

> Questões

1 - O problema que estou tendo é quando tento cadastrar um usuário utilizando a página *cadastro_usuario.jsp*, preencho os campos corretamente, porém quando eu clico no botão cadastrar é me apresentado o seguinte erro:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report
message Internal Server Error
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction

root cause

org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction

root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

Não sei onde eu errei ou se é falta de alguma outra configuração então a quem possa interessar agradeço deste já.

---

### UPDATE

**HibernateUsuarioDAO**

```
@Repository
public class HibernateUsuarioDAO implements UsuarioDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public HibernateUsuarioDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void salvar(Usuario pUsuario) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(pUsuario);
    }

    @Override
    public void atualizar(Usuario pUsuario) {
        if (pUsuario.getPermissao() == null
                || pUsuario.getPermissao().size() == 0) {
            Usuario usuarioPermissao = this.carregar(pUsuario.getCodigo());
            pUsuario.setPermissao(usuarioPermissao.getPermissao());
            this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(usuarioPermissao);
        }

        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(pUsuario);
    }

    @Override
    public void excluir(Usuario pUsuario) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(pUsuario);
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario carregar(Integer pCodigo) {
        return (Usuario) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(
                Usuario.class, pCodigo);
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario carregarPorLogin(String pLogin) {
        String hql = "select t from Usuario t where t.login = :login";
        Query consulta = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                hql);
        consulta.setString("login", pLogin);
        return (Usuario) consulta.uniqueResult();
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario carregarPorRg(String pRg) {
        String hql = "select t from Usuario t where t.rg = :rg";
        Query consulta = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                hql);
        consulta.setString("rg", pRg);
        return (Usuario) consulta.uniqueResult();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Usuario> listar() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Usuario.class).list();
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE 2

**Log do Glassfish**

```
Server shutdown initiated
Unregistered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@18b0c12 from service registry.
FileMonitoring shutdown
JMXStartupService: Stopped JMXConnectorServer: null
JMXStartupService and JMXConnectors have been shut down.
WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource]
RAR7094: __ds_jdbc_ra shutdown successful.
Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)
Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 130ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8.080]
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 6ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8.181]
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4.848]
Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 5ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3.700]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.web.glue, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.glue [263]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp [149]], State = [READY]
visiting unvisited references
Grave: Exception while visiting javax.swing.JTable
Grave: SEC5054: Certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  ...
]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
...
]
SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
Created virtual server server
Created virtual server __asadmin
Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
Virtual server server loaded default web module 
visiting unvisited references
WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Grave: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
Grave: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
Grave: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'DispatcherServlet'
visiting unvisited references
HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
Grave: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
Grave: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Grave: log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Loading application [sgct-web] at [/sgct]
Loading application sgct-web done in 25.502 ms
Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (4.027ms), startup services(27.485ms), total(31.512ms)
Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
visiting unvisited references
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@10e7b89 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@78459f.
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.hk2.hk2, 2.1.92) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2 [118]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service [58]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client [67]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api [230]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl [231]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet-api, 3.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet-api [147]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet.jsp-api, 2.3.1) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet.jsp-api [148]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.el.javax.el, 3.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.el.javax.el [132]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.jsftemplating, 2.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.jsftemplating [186]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider [63]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.pkg.client, 1.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.pkg.client [229]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin [46]], State = [READY]
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://brito-01.mshome.net:8686/jndi/rmi://brito-01.mshome.net:8686/jmxrmi
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin [57]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin [51]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin [50]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin [54]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin [55]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin [56]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin [60]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin [59]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin [49]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin [52]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin [53]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin [47]], State = [READY]
visiting unvisited references
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.hk2.hk2, 2.1.92) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2 [118]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service [58]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client [67]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api [230]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl [231]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet-api, 3.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet-api [147]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet.jsp-api, 2.3.1) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet.jsp-api [148]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.el.javax.el, 3.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.el.javax.el [132]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.jsftemplating, 2.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.jsftemplating [186]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider [63]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.pkg.client, 1.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.pkg.client [229]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin [46]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin [57]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin [51]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin [50]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin [54]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin [55]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin [56]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin [60]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [48]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin [59]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin [49]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin [52]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin [53]], State = [READY]
this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin [47]], State = [READY]
Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) para o contexto ''
Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
Informações: Loading application __admingui done in 6.862 ms
Advertência: StandardWrapperValve[DispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet DispatcherServlet threw exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at org.sgct.dao.impl.HibernateUsuarioDAO.salvar(HibernateUsuarioDAO.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.salvar(Unknown Source)
    at org.sgct.rn.UsuarioService.salvar(UsuarioService.java:28)
    at org.sgct.web.controllers.UsuarioController.executarCadastro(UsuarioController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
```

Comment: Aparentemente as configurações relacionadas à JTA estão corretas. Pode postar os logs do GlassFish e o código do seu DAO onde você está injetando a Session?

Comment: É apenas um chute (baseado na possibilidade de um *bug*), mas tente sem repetir a anotação `@Transactional` no método (já que a anotação foi definida na classe toda).

Comment: @utluiz, eu tirei a anotação `@Transactional` do método `salvar()` e dos outros métodos mas o erro ainda persiste. Eu também fiz a remoção da anotação `@Transactional` que está na assinatura da classe e coloquei esta anotação nos métodos, mas ainda ocorre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Certo, @klaytonbrito. Notei ainda que nas nas linhas de log ` at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy185.salvar(Unknown Source) at org.sgct.rn.UsuarioService.salvar(UsuarioService.java:28)` há uma chamada direta, como se o Spring AOP não estivesse interceptando a chamada, o que faria com que a anotação `@Transactional` não iniciasse uma transação. Faça um teste: coloca a anotação no método `salvar` da classe **DAO** e veja o que acontece.

Comment: Para informá-los, estou utilizando a versão _4.0.6_ do Spring. E estou utilizando _BOM_ (_Bill of Materials_) do _Spring 4.0.6_ para sincronizar as versões dos componentes do Spring.

Comment: @utluiz, eu retirei todas as anotações `@Transactional` da classe `UsuarioService` e coloquei esta anotação no método `salvar()` da classe `HibernateUsuarioDAO`, mas o mesmo erro continua a ocorrer.

Comment: Cara, vamos fazer alguns testes. Se funcionar vira resposta. 1) Some com o AspectJ: `<tx:annotation-drivem>` 2) Seta a propriedade do hibernate: `hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup`.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, o problema da exceção sobre `JTA transaction` foi resolvido somente retirando o AspectJ da tag `<tx:annotation-driven />` que você citou, deixando o modo default (`mode="proxy"`). Qual o motivo que levou essa exceção a ocorrer eu desconheço, talvez um bug. Mas surgiu outra exceção: `java.sql.SQLException: No database selected`. Esse problema ocorreu como vocês sabem por causa da falta da definição de um banco de dados no driver do MySQL, que no meu caso é configurado no pool de conexões do Glassfish.

Comment: Completando minha resposta anterior, eu estou falando dessa exceção porque há um erro no tutorial de configuração do MySQL com Glassfish ([aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html)), pois como descrito no tutorial é preciso definir uma propriedade chamada `DatabaseName`, porém, talvez pelo Glassfish, essa propriedade não é reconhecida, então o nome do banco de dados deve ser definido na propriedade `URL` para funcionar corretamente, como descrito [aqui](http://computingat40s.wordpress.com/how-to-setup-a-jdbc-connection-in-glassfish/).

Comment: Olá klayton, fico feliz em ajudar, vou transformar o comentário em resposta. Sobre o Driver + GlassFish, acho estranho, tenho uma instância configurada com o `databaseName` (ok, é no GlassFish 3 e uma versão antiga do Driver). Que eu saiba da para configurar das duas maneiras.

Comment: Bom, obrigado a vocês por me ajudarem. Sobre o driver do MySQL e o Glassfish, não sei te dizer se é por causa das versões, mas neste meu caso o `DatabaseName` não funcionou e causou a exceção do `MySQLException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolução do problema do autor. Remover o `mode="aspectj"` do `<tx:annotation-driven />`.

Motivo, não foi habilitado o `weaver` (para mais informações ver: [SOen The Old “@Transactional from within the same class”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615728/the-old-transactional-from-within-the-same-class-situation)), porém, salvo necessidades especiais como ter que chamar métodos transacionais na mesma classe (sem injetar uma referência), a estratégia de proxy é mais do que suficiente.